# How to access a local directory, zip it and POST it to an endpoint Using only Javascript from client side

Tags: javascript, gzip, client-side

> Full disclaimer My knowledge of javascript is really basic

Is there a way to do the following from the client side using javascript?

1. Access the local file system.
2. zip an entire directory.
3. Use POST request to send the zip to an API endpoint.

### Context

I'm working on an automation project (using Robotframework and Selenium) that test a webUI in a remote host. before start testing i define a custome `user-data-dir` so chrome will drop all the files from the browser session in there, After the webUI testing is done, I access the `user-data-dir` zip the content and send it to an endpoint I made in Flask.

> I want to create a persistance so next test case with a log in user as prerequisit can start from this custom session and i dont need to run loging test case --> I want to follwo an Atomic test cases approuch

Currently, I have a HTML form which I use after the test finish, in other words, after the test finish, I open another tab and navigate to the flask server endpoint where I have a form, and I submit the folder.

To submit a folder I'm using webkitdir

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('upload.upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <p><input type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to change this approach and use javascript instead.

> Why don't use javascript to log in before the test case start, this will satisfy the prerequisite and you won't need to use the login screen or play with `user-data-dir` -> yeah,  It sounds better, however, I need to continue down this path by using `user-data-dir` did.

> I know is not a good practice to use client-side javascript to access the local file system, but I don't have other options to access it. SSH is not allowed and I cannot run a daemon or any background process on the remote machine.
> RDP or RDC is not available either.

All the examples I read contain AJAX, JQUERY, or other libraries, but, first, I'm not familiar so took me a long time to find they are not suitable because all of them need an HTML form, and I want to avoid HTML.

Comment: If you mean "with a browser", you don't. The best you can do is prompt the user to select a file using `<input type="file">`. This is mainly due to browser security. A different path that might be available to you is RDP (remote desktop) or RPC (remote procedure call).

Comment: We'll need more information about why your solutions were rejected. This site is about programming, not about dealing with company policy. Also, since it seems you've exhausted your javascript options, we're only going to be able to offer non-javascript alternatives.

Comment: @ouroburus Understood, I know the purpose of the side, but I wanted to remark, I'm aware there are other ways to do it, and potentially more efficient and secure.
I already have a solution with a form and `<input...>`  but arguably not a good solution either.
RDP and RPC are not possible because the remote host doesn't support them.
No, About whether is possible or not, I cannot be sure, my lack of knowledge on javascript is an anchor, thus my decision to ask the community. I appreciate your answer though.